# BigQuery - Concatenate multiple rows into a single row

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with 2 columns:

```
id|name
1|John
1|Tom
1|Bob
2|Jack
2|Tim
```

Expected output: Concatenate names grouped by id

```
id|Text
1|John,Tom,Bob
2|Jack,Tim
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL:

```sql
#standardSQL
--WITH yourTable AS (
--  SELECT 1 AS id, 'John' AS name UNION ALL
--  SELECT 1, 'Tom' UNION ALL
--  SELECT 1, 'Bob' UNION ALL
--  SELECT 2, 'Jack' UNION ALL
--  SELECT 2, 'Tim' 
--)
SELECT 
  id, 
  STRING_AGG(name ORDER BY name) AS Text 
FROM yourTable 
GROUP BY id
```

Optional `ORDER BY name` within `STRING_CONCAT` allows you to get out sorted list of names as below

```sql
id  Text     
1   Bob,John,Tom     
2   Jack,Tim
```

For Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS Text   
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```

If you would need to output sorted list here, you can use below (formally - it is not guaranteed by BigQuery Legacy SQL to get sorted list - but for most practical cases I had - it worked)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS Text 
FROM (
  SELECT id, name 
  FROM yourTable 
  ORDER BY name
)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This just helped me, happily upvoting

Answer (score 2):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT

`SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS Text FROM <dataset>.<table> GROUP BY id`

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` for Legacy SQL and `STRING_AGG()` for Standard SQL