# Approaches for creating a matrix for collaborative filtering product recommendations

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, recommendation-engine

I am exploring recommender systems in python, so far I have used a KNN model to suggest brands with a 'users like you also purchased...' methodology. My data table has a row for every customer and a column for every brand, populated with `1` or `0` to indicate whether or not the customer has purchased that brand.

I'd now like the take this forward to product level recommendations, but struggling to see how this approach would scale. I tried the same approach, but was unable to query my database (BigQuery) with a query large enough to generate a column for every product (10,000+).

For example, my source is Google Analytics daily data exported into BigQuery and I am creating my input data per the example below:

```
SELECT
  customDimension.value AS UserID,
  MAX(IF(UPPER(hits_product.productSKU) LIKE "SKU1",1,0)) AS SKU1,
  MAX(IF(UPPER(hits_product.productSKU) LIKE "SKU2",1,0)) AS SKU2,
  MAX(IF(UPPER(hits_product.productSKU) LIKE "SKU3",1,0)) AS SKU3
  # plus 10,000 more...
  FROM
  `PROJECT.DATASET.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST (hits) AS hits
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
CROSS JOIN
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
WHERE
  parse_DATE('%y%m%d',
    _table_suffix) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 day)
  AND customDimension.index = 2
  AND customDimension.value NOT IN ("true","false","undefined")
  AND customDimension.value IS NOT NULL
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Ecommerce'
  AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = 'Purchase'
GROUP BY
  UserID
```

Running this query with a line for each SKU generates the error:

> The query is too large. The maximum query length is 256.000K characters, including comments and white space characters.

How would one create product level recommendations in this case? Is data normally ingested into python in a different form and transformed into a maxrix in code?

I am completely stumped at this point, so any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "...was unable to query my database (BigQuery) with a query large enough to generate a column for every product (10,000+)."? It sounds like you're unable to perform that 1-0 expansion in BigQuery, no? To answer your question, yes, you could do this matrix-creation in Python. You'll just need to be wary of the dimensions of your data if you also want to do the recommendation "math" in Python as well, depending on the specs on your machine... How many customers (rows) versus how many columns (products) will be created?

Comment: Another thing you could do would be to take a Pareto-style approach to the products - limiting the number of products in-scope for recommendation. What does the distribution of your product purchases look like? Is it pretty heavily skewed to the right? This could even extend to customers, I suppose -- not making recommendations for the bottom *p* percent of lowest-value customers...

Comment: @blacksite I've updated my question with a sample query, but essentially your assumption is correct! If I were to create the matrix in python what would be the best format to extract from BigQuery in?

Comment: Absolutely right, the matrix will be largely sparse - every customer has purchased at least one item but most of the SKUs will be unpurchased, I'd be confident slicing this up, but I'd need to get the data in first?

Comment: One more question... So the raw columns/schema of your BigTable table is something like `[customer_id, sku1, sku2, sku3, ..., skuN]`, and not something like `[customer_id, sku]` with one row per customer per product purchased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to efficiently create that 1-0 (one-hot-esque) encoding you want in BigQuery (or really any dialect of SQL), but I definitely know how to make it in Python.

Probably the most effective way of aggregating these data for use in Python would be to do something like the following...

It looks like your BigQuery table follows this structure:

[image]

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997005/bigquery-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row), it looks like you can aggregate each SKU into one row using something like this:

```
SELECT UserID, STRING_AGG(SKU) AS SKU_string FROM my_transactions_table GROUP BY UserID
```

Which should give you this (taking the example table from above):

[image]

From there, it's really easy to consume these data in Python:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/test.csv', sep='\t')
>>> df
   UserID SKU_string
0       1      a,b,c
1       2        b,b
2       3      c,b,a
```

We can use scikit-learn's CountVectorizer class to count the occurrences of each product for each user:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(','))
>>> X = vec.fit_transform(df['SKU_string'])
>>> X
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
>>> pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vec.get_feature_names())
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  0  2  0
2  1  1  1
```

If you like, join that matrix back to the DataFrame and other user metadata you might have selected:

```
>>> df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=['product_{}'.format(x) for x in vec.get_feature_names()]))
>>> df
   UserID SKU_string  product_a  product_b  product_c
0       1      a,b,c          1          1          1
1       2        b,b          0          2          0
2       3      c,b,a          1          1          1
```

However, I would most likely recommend against this if you have as many different products as you say. 10,000 products creates 10,000 additional, **not-sparse** columns which can eat up a lot of memory if you have a lot of customers.

Additionally, if you want to convert that `X` object (a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`) strictly to a one-zero encoding, try this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> def booleanize_csr_matrix(mat):
...     ''' Convert sparse matrix with positive integer elements to 1s '''
...     nnz_inds = mat.nonzero()
...     keep = np.where(mat.data > 0)[0]
...     n_keep = len(keep)
...     result = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(
...             (np.ones(n_keep), (nnz_inds[0][keep], nnz_inds[1][keep])),
...             shape=mat.shape
...     )
...     return result
... 
>>> pd.DataFrame(booleanize_csr_matrix(X).toarray(), columns=vec.get_feature_names())
     a    b    c
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

From there, you can use a variety of algorithms for recommending items on a user basis... You might look at [`sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) for measuring the angles between each user's purchase vector.

Comment: Thanks you, this looks like an approach I can definitely apply and take forward!

Answer (score 1):

Usually at times, when our sql queries looks more like server logs (long and lengthy), its probably time to rethink about strategy and structure of data and about trying to engineer ways around it.

In your specific case, you are trying to construct a query with absolute elements, which usually is not a good practice. So, the thing you need is to dump your skus (all of them) in a BigQuery table. Once that is done, then you can use `ARRAYS` in BigQuery to generate your one-hot encodings (and what not). Here is a short sample, using public GA data:

```
with listskus as (
  -- this is fake data. 
  -- replace it with your sku listing query (i.e. select sku as listsku from myskutable)
  select 
    listsku from 
    unnest(generate_array(0, 11000, 1)) 
  as listsku
),
data as (
  select 
    visitId as userid,
    array(
      (
        select 
          if(p.productSKU like concat('%',cast(l.listsku as string)), 1, 0) 
        from unnest(hits.product) p 
        left outer join listskus l on 1=1
      )
    ) as onehotvector
  from 
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
  unnest(hits) hits
)
select userid, onehotvector from data
```