# BigQuery - Concatenate multiple columns into a single column for large numbers of columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have data that looks like:

| row | col1 | col2 | col3 | ... | coln |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | null | B | ... | null |
| 2 | null | B | C | ... | D |
| 3 | null | null | null | ... | A |

I want to condense the columns together to get:

| row | final |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B |
| 2 | B, C, D |
| 3 | A |

The order of the letters doesn't matter, and if the solution includes the nulls eg. A,null,B,null ect. I can work out how to remove them later. I've used up to coln as I have about 200 columns to condense.

I've tried a few things and if I were trying to condense rows I could use STRING_AGG() [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997005/bigquery-concatenate-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row)

Additionally I could do this:

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(col1,", ",col2,", ",col3,", ",coln) #ect.
 FROM mytable
```

However, this would involve writing out each column name by hand which isn't really feasible. Is there a better way to achieve this ideally for the whole table.

Additionally CONCAT returns NULL if any value is NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
select row, 
  (select string_agg(col, ', ' order by offset)
  from unnest(split(trim(format('%t', (select as struct t.* except(row))), '()'), ', ')) col with offset
  where not upper(col) = 'NULL'
  ) as final
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not in exact format that you asked for, but you can try if this simplifies things for you:

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(mytable) FROM mytable
```

If you want the exact format, you can write a regex to extract values from the output JSON string.